# Exploring the Meaning and Use of the Phrase 'Night Night'

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, connotations

I've recently encountered the phrase "Night Night," which piqued my curiosity. I understand it's used as a form of saying goodnight, but I'm interested in delving deeper into its meaning and usage. Specifically, I would like to know:

What is the exact meaning and connotation of "Night Night"? Does it differ in any way from a simple "Goodnight"?

Comment: This does not seem like a history question, nor do I think that you should ask about both meaning and history in the same question.

Answer (score 19):

The expression *night-night* is an example of the linguistic phenomenon **reduplication**. Wikipedia has a page dedicated to it

> [Reduplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduplication#English) is used in inflections to convey a grammatical function, such as plurality, intensification, etc., and in lexical derivation to create new words. It is often used when a speaker adopts a tone more "expressive" or figurative than ordinary speech and is also often, but not exclusively, [iconic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iconicity) in meaning.
>
> **Exact reduplications**: Ack ack, aye-aye, back-to-back, blah-blah, boo-boo, bye-bye, chin-chin, […] **night-night**, no-no, papa, pee-pee, […]  ta-ta, there-there, tut-tut, tutu, wah-wah, wee-wee, yo-yo. While in many forms of English, exact reduplications can also be used to emphasise the strength of a word ("He wants it now now"),[…].

Comment: As others have pointed out, a lot of these expressions are 'baby-talk'. You would say "night-night" to a child, or to an adult only in informal and/or intimate circumstances.

Comment: Right, although "bye-bye" graduated to adult use, although still very informal. @KateBunting

Comment: @Barmar: Yes yes. Very very. Ha ha...

Comment: While good info, this does not appear to answer the actual question (meaning and connotation).

Comment: @fectin “*It is often used when a speaker adopts a tone more "expressive" or figurative than ordinary speech*“ The OP also asked: *I'm interested in delving* **deeper into its meaning and** ***usage***.

Comment: "Specifically, I would like to know:

What is the exact meaning and connotation of "Night Night"? Does it differ in any way from a simple "Goodnight"?"

Comment: @fectin the meaning is "[good] night, [good] night", reduplication is just a way of emphasising the meaning or a means of demonstrating affection by repeating it twice.  It was explained by nschnied and also by Style before I decided to post my answer.

Answer (score 13):

My impression is that it is a child-friendly expression, something that would especially be used within the home. Perhaps by a small child who is not yet able to form complex phrases. A playful variant is "Nighty Night". Merriam-Webster [agrees](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/night%20night).

Comment: I've also heard young children (or their parents) use the phrase, "Go night night", meaning, "Go to sleep".

Answer (score 8):

Compared to a simple "Goodnight," I think "Night Night" is generally more affectionate and conveys warmth and closeness. It's often used among friends, family members, or romantic partners to express a sense of intimacy and caring.

Comment: Do you have any sources to support your answer?

Comment: My usage agrees with your answer. Additionally I would almost always use "Night night" at bed-time, while I might use "Good night" to colleagues at the end of a late shift or to strangers when leaving somewhere late at night.

Comment: As a native British English speaker, this fits my experience.  It’s certainly not just used with children as [nschneid’s answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/346756/851) suggests — it’s common within families, or between close friends in somewhat intimate settings — but it is definitely restricted to intimate/affectionate contexts, compared with “Good night”.

Comment: @PLL In contrast, I'm a native Canadian English speaker, and to me "night night" sounds exclusively childish. I would only use it with friends if I was being goofy (playful) and instead I would use "g'night" or just "night".

Answer (score 0):

I use “nighty night” as a variation of “goodnight” to sound more friendly, casual, or colloquial. I often shorten this to “night night”. It has a subtle tongue-in-cheek feeling of irony or humor, yet sincere kindness. It passes off as “nighty night”, but it sounds slightly absurd, since I guess it has the background connotation of imperfect grammar or small-child talk.

If you would like a rule of thumb for usage, I would simply place them on a spectrum of neutral-formal-standard to personal-idiosyncratic-colloquial-personable: Goodnight < Nighty night < Night night.

You can continue this theme of friendly, ironic small-child talk by adding something like “Don’t let the bedbugs bite.”